# learnyounode Juggling Async Solution not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have looked at other threads on this topic, but still can't figure out why mine doesn't work. Any thoughts?

```
var files = process.argv.slice(2);
var count = 0;
var results = [];
var http = require('http');
function printOut() {
    for (var t = 0; t < results.length; t++) {
        console.log(results[t]);
    }
}

function run(id){
    http.get(files[id], function(response) {
        var output = '';
        count++;
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on("data", function(data) {
            output += data;
        });
        response.on("end", function() {
            count--;
            //console.log(count);
            results[id] = output;
            if (count === 0) {
                printOut();
            }
        });
        }).on('error', function(e){
                console.log("error:" + e.message);
            });

}

for(var j = 0; j < files.length; j++){
    //console.log('Running ' + (j+1) + 'st get');
    run(j);
}
```

I have been looking at this for hours and can't figure out why it doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running this?

I changed one line in your program:
`http.get('http://www.google.com/', function(response) {`

And executed: `node index.js hello` (the `hello` is just there as a placeholder, since your for-loop expects a parameter). It worked fine for me. So maybe you need to elaborate a little?